# Tabela Dinâmica com Bootstrap e JQuery- wenzhixin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Há um repositório no github, [bootstrap-table-examples](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples), que mostra uma tabela dinâmica e muito interessante de ser reaproveitada. Porém, por falta de conhecimento não consegui compreender o projeto 100%. Contudo, tem um trecho de código fiquei muito interessado e mesmo procurando na internet não encontrei nada similar, **que é modo como a tabela é construída.**

No arquivo **welcome.html** a tabela está sendo construída por JQuery passando parâmetros para ele. Segue o código:

```
var $table = $('#table'),
    $remove = $('#remove'),
    selections = [];

function initTable() {
    $table.bootstrapTable({
        height: getHeight(),
        columns: [
            [
                {
                    field: 'state',
                    checkbox: true,
                    rowspan: 2,
                    align: 'center',
                    valign: 'middle'
                }, {
                    title: 'Item ID',
                    field: 'id',
                    rowspan: 2,
                    align: 'center',
                    valign: 'middle',
                    sortable: true,
                    footerFormatter: totalTextFormatter
                }, {
                    title: 'Item Detail',
                    colspan: 3,
                    align: 'center'
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    field: 'name',
                    title: 'Item Name',
                    sortable: true,
                    editable: true,
                    footerFormatter: totalNameFormatter,
                    align: 'center'
                }, {
                    field: 'price',
                    title: 'Item Price',
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'center',
                    editable: {
                        type: 'text',
                        title: 'Item Price',
                        validate: function (value) {
                            value = $.trim(value);
                            if (!value) {
                                return 'This field is required';
                            }
                            if (!/^\$/.test(value)) {
                                return 'This field needs to start width $.'
                            }
                            var data = $table.bootstrapTable('getData'),
                                index = $(this).parents('tr').data('index');
                            console.log(data[index]);
                            return '';
                        }
                    },
                    footerFormatter: totalPriceFormatter
                }, {
                    field: 'operate',
                    title: 'Item Operate',
                    align: 'center',
                    events: operateEvents,
                    formatter: operateFormatter
                }
            ]
        ]
    });
```

Gostaria de entender mais de como isso é feito! E também, se possível, passar outros links para eu verificar e estudar também de outras fontes!
E, se possível, opine se é de fato mais interessante montar tabela de modo dinâmico assim ou fazer mesmo no código html!

Muito grato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caro Wesley, a tabela não está sendo construída por JQuery.
O fato de fazer:

```
var $table = $('#table');
```

está apenas selecionando o elemento `#table` do DOM.
O código

```
$table.bootstrapTable({...});
```

está chamando a função `bootstrapTable`, que provavelmente é um prototype de uma função que os criadores da biblioteca adicionaram a um elemento JQuery. Essa função inicializa o elemento `$table` com o *object* definido por `{ height: getHeight(), columns: [...] }`, onde `height` e `columns` são algumas das propriedades, ou atributos, desse *javascript object*.

Se você quiser brincar um pouco estendendo o *prototype* do JQuery, você pode fazer algo parecido:

```
$.prototype.nomeDeUmaFuncao = function() { console.log('teste nova custom function do JQuery'); };
```

e aí você terá estendido o JQuery com sua nova função. A biblioteca que você está utilizando provavelmente fez isso para colocar essa função de inicialização da tabela.

Uma outra tabela dinâmica que gosto de usar também é a [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), um plugin JQuery também para dados tabelados.

Espero ter esclarecido suas dúvidas. :)

Comment: Grato por ter ajudado! Desculpa a demora de dar um feedback.